# Why is my answer wrong? Given a fair coin, what is the expected number of tosses to get two heads consecutively?

Tags: probability, proof-explanation, expected-value

> Question: Given a fair coin, what is the expected number of tosses to get two heads consecutively?

My attempt:

Let $X$ be the number of tosses to get two consecutive heads.
Then we are asked to find
$$E(X) = \sum_{x=2}^\infty x\cdot P(X=x).$$
Note that 
$$P(X=x)  = \left( \frac{1}{2} \right)^x.$$
So 
$$E(X) = \sum_{x=2}^\infty x\cdot \left( \frac{1}{2} \right)^x = \left[\sum_{x=1}^\infty x\cdot \left( \frac{1}{2} \right)^x\right] - \frac{1}{2} = 1.5. $$
However, the answer given is $6.$

Comment: Your $P(X=x)$ makes no sense. Think again what $X$ is and what is necessary for it to attain some value.

Comment: FYI Your calculation is for "get one head (consecutively)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $X = 2,$ there is only one possible sequence of flips: HH,
probability $\frac14$ as your formula says.

For $X=3$ there is again only one possible sequence: THH,
probability $\frac18$ as your formula says.

But for $X=4$ you could have TTHH or HTHH. So $P(X=4)=\frac18,$ not $\frac1{16}$ as implied by your formula.

For $X=5$ the possibilities are TTTHH, THTHH, and HTTHH,
probability $\frac{3}{32}.$

For $X=6$ you could have TTTTHH, TTHTHH, THTTHH, HTTTHH, or HTHTHH,
probability $\frac{5}{64}.$

After $X=3$ all your probabilities are too small. That is why you get a result much less than the correct result.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have an expected number of flips less than 2.

Before your first flip you are at least 2 flips away from completion.

Now you can flip a heads, or a tails.

If you get Tails you are still 2 flips from completion.

If you get Heads, now you might be one flip away, but if you get a tails next, putting you are back to square one.

Lets call initial state $A.$
$E(A)$ is the expected number of flips to move to completion.

Your options then look like

$\begin {array}{} 
\text{Result}& \text{Probability} & \text{End State} & \text {Number of flips}\\
HH& \frac 14& \text{Complete} & 2\\
HT& \frac 14& A & 2\\
T & \frac 12 & A & 1 \end{array}$

$E(A) = (\frac 14)(2) + (\frac 14) (E(A) + 2) + (\frac 12) (E(A) + 1)$

Now solve for $E(A)$

$\frac 14 E(A) = \frac 12 + \frac 12 + \frac 12\\
E(A) = 6$